# ultimo registro condicionado

Tags: mysql

Hola a todos tengo una tabla en `MySQL` donde tengo muchos registros, quiero obtener el último para una condición específica, tengo los campos:

```
Id int auto_increment
Codpro int
SaldoInicial decimal
Saldofinal decimal
cantidad decimal
```

Quiero hallar el último registro para un código específico (`Codpro`)
Ejemplo:

```
Id     Codpro   Saldoinicial cantidad Saldofinal
1       2526       2562         100      2462
2       2632       2514.25       50     2564.5
3       2526       2462         200      2262 
......
12512   2526       251425       210      145214
```

Así puede haber muchos registros para el código `2526` ubicados en muchos lugares de la tabla, pero quiero obtener el último para es código solo y puede haber muchos códigos.

Espero se entienda para obtener respuestas.

---

con eso esta resuelto la primera parte del problema, ahora quiero resolver la segunda parte, o sea, si se cambiase algun saldofinal en un momento determinado, ¿como actualizo los que vienen despues segun Id para ese codigo?
Ejemplo tengo:
Id  Codpro  Saldoinicial    cantidad    Saldofinal TtipoOperacion
1   2526       20              10         10         salida
2   2536       35              5          30         salida
3   2526       10              100        110        entrada
......
25  2526       110              25        85         salida

......
50  2526       85             50         135         entrada 
y  asi sucesivamente puede haber muchos registros para ese codigo, pero quiero actualizar con un update todos los registro que le continuan en la tabla, si cambio en el Id 3 la cantidad de 100 a 500,  entonces Saldofinal es 10+500= 510 porque es entrada, entonces en el siguiente Id 25 el saldoinicial sera 510 y el saldofinal seria: 510-25=85 porque es salida, y asi sucesivamente quiero actualizar todos los registros que continuan mediante un update.

Comment: Tu pregunta es un poco liosa, te recomendaría editarla usando saltos de linea, ejemplos de tu base de datos, y sobre todo... **comparte** el codigo/consulta que has intentado hasta el momento para tener un punto del que partir

Comment: Gracias por responder, tengo una tabla donde guardo todos los procesos de un sistema de facturacion entradas y salidas para diferentes productos, donde guardo el saldo que tenia el producto antes de la operacion (Saldoinicial) y el que queda despues de la operacion (Saldofinal),  aqui cada producto tiene un codigo (Codpro), pero en algun momento determinado quiero mediante una consulta en mi BD a esa tabla obtener el Saldofinal para un dia especifico, y esa consulta es la que no  se construir.

Answer (score 3):

Dado que la columna ID es auto_increment podrías *creer* que el mayor valor siempre fue el último en ser ingresado, pero ésto no siempre es cierto, y es por eso que, en principio, la respuesta es que **no es posible obtener "el más nuevo" usando esa columna**.

Por ejemplo, si dos instancias de un programa ejecutan transacciones casi al mismo tiempo, es posible que una instancia reserve un ID (digamos, 100) y la otra otro (digamos, 101), pero la de 101 finalice antes que la de 100, con lo cual **el mayor valor no representa al más nuevo**.

Si para tu caso particular ésto no es un problema (porque no hay más que una única instancia, o porque estás analizando datos históricos que ya no están siendo actualizados), podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE Codpro = 2526 AND Id = (SELECT MAX(Id) FROM tabla WHERE Codpro = 2526);
```

Esto lo podemos ver como dos subconsultas. Una:

```
SELECT MAX(Id) FROM tabla WHERE Codpro=2526
```

buscará el mayor de los valores para Id entre los registros que incluyan al Codpro 2526.
Para el ejemplo, digamos que eso devuelve Id=100
La siguiente subconsulta, entonces, haría ésto:

```
SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE Codpro = 2526 AND Id = 100
```

Que, para ser correctos, deberíamos decir que es el registro de mayor valor entre los que incluyen al Codpro 2526, **pero ésto no implica que sea el más reciente.**

Answer (score 2):

Teniendo una columna `id` autoincrementada es una ventaja para este tipo de consultas, una sugerencia es realizar la consulta ordenando por el `id` de manera `DESC` limitando a 1 el numero de registros retornados;

```sql
SELECT Id, Codpro ,SaldoInicial,Saldofinal,cantidad 
FROM mi_tabla
WHERE Codpro = '2526'
ORDER BY Id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Con esto obtienes el ultimo registro insertado.